# Number of threads created is 12 but still runs only on one core of 12 core-CPU

Tags: multithreading, matlab, openmp, mex, single-threaded

I have a strange issue. I have a Matlab mexfunction in which I have used OpenMP directives/functions. Before the beginning of a parallel section (parallel for...), I use commands to set and print the number of threads created:

---

```
nP = omp_get_num_procs();
omp_set_num_threads(nP);
mexPrintf("\n Num of threads= %d\n",nP);
.
.
.
#pragma omp parallel for shared(...)
```

---

The issue is, at the output, it prints 'Num of threads= 12', but the parallel section which follows does not run on all 12 cores of my machine (but on only 1 core). My program was written long back and I had no such issue earlier (it ran on all 12 cores). Recently, the system got corrupted and OS (Win 7 Pro) was reinstalled with updated version of Matlab 2011b (earlier 2010b). I also installed Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Is there anything I am missing or overlooking?

Comment: Did you configure Windows to use only one core? http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/66504-processors-limit-number-used-windows-7-a.html. Windows Server 2008 has also limits depending on the editon you did buy how many cores are used (http://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/sample/DOMIS/update/2008/02feb/0208ws2plp_ch.htm).

Comment: @AloisKraus: The question says Windows 7 Pro, which supports two physical processor sockets (and many cores/socket).

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling mex functions inside the `omp parallel for` block?

I've had the best luck extracting pointers first sequentially, then processing in parallel, and then loading results into matlab variables sequentially at the end.  That way the parallel code is pure C++, no mex functions called (that could wait for a shared lock).

Of course, make sure you're actually compiling with OpenMP enabled... otherwise the directives get ignored and you end up with sequential code.